# How to auto paste a value if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I want a functionality, i have a list with checkbox i if checkbox is selected i want to paste the selected value in a text field.[image]

Something like appeared in above image.

edited:

```
<table id="userTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Id</th>
                <th>Order Proposed Id</th>
                <th>Order Proposed Date</th>
                <th>Store Id</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <%for(Order orderSList:orderList){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=orderSList.getOrderId()%></td>
                 <td><%=orderSList.getOrderProposedId()%></td>
                 <td><%=orderSList.getOrderProposedDate()%></td>
                 <td><%=orderSList.getStoreId()%></td>
                 <td><input type="checkbox" name="<portlet:namespace/>notSubmitList" value="<%=orderSList.getOrderId()%>" class="case" /></td>
            </tr>
          <%} %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 <script>
```

Comment: What does your table markup look like? Does the textarea have an `id`?

Comment: use onchange function and write the val via jquery into the textfield

Comment: you do not "paste" a value, you copy it, big difference in wording

Comment: yes textarea would have an id!

Comment: loop over the checked boxes onchange and build the string....

Comment: You have to provide us your HTML structure so we can help you more.

Comment: @PierreC. i just wanted if someone have example fiddle for that. I have just written code.

Comment: @Akash Do you want all selected values in the text field?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var selectedValue = function(id, _this){
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedIN');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(_this != checkboxes[i]){
      checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }      
  }
  if(_this.checked){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =       document.getElementById(id).value;
  }else{
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
}
  }
```

```css
input:-moz-read-only { /* For Firefox */
    background-color: none;
    border:none;
}

input:read-only { 
    background-color: none;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="userTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Id</th>
                <th>Order Proposed Id</th>
                <th>Order Proposed Date</th>
                <th>Store Id</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1001</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" value="123" readonly="true" id="opID_1"/>
              </td>
               <td>Order Proposed Date</td>
                <td>Store Id</td>
              <td>
                <input type='checkbox'  onchange="selectedValue('opID_1',this)" class="selectedIN"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5555</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="456" readonly="true" id="opID_2"/>
            </td>
             <td>Order Proposed Date</td>
              <td>Store Id</td>
            <td>
              <input type='checkbox' onchange="selectedValue('opID_2',this)" class="selectedIN"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5555</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="789" readonly="true" id="opID_3"/>
            </td>
             <td>Order Proposed Date</td>
              <td>Store Id</td>
            <td>
              <input type='checkbox' onchange="selectedValue('opID_3',this)" class="selectedIN"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5555</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="999" readonly="true" id="opID_4"/>
            </td>
             <td>Order Proposed Date</td>
              <td>Store Id</td>
            <td>
              <input type='checkbox' onchange="selectedValue('opID_4',this)" class="selectedIN"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<div class='selected_values'>
  <strong>Selected Value: <span id="result"></span></strong>
</div>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the checkbox checked or not with [onchange](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of Jquery. After that you just select the its Order Proposal Id using by [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) functions.

I added Jquery 2.1.1 to the below snippet.

```js
$("input").on("change",function(){
  var thiz = $(this);
  
  if(thiz.is(':checked')){
    var value = thiz.parent().parent().find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
  
    $(".selected_values span").text(value);
  }
  else{
    $(".selected_values span").text("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Order Id</th>
    <th>Order Proposal Id</th>
    <th>Order Proposal Date</th>
    <th>Store Id</th>
    <th>Store Id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1001</td>
    <td>2016-10-21</td>
    <td>1709</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>82715421</td>
    <td>2017-05-22</td>
    <td>525</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>82715422</td>
    <td>2016-12-31</td>
    <td>525</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class='selected_values'>
  <strong>Selected Value: <span></span></strong>
</div>
```

**Pure Javascript Solution**

```js
var value_span = document.getElementById("selected_value");

function printSelectedValue(e, selected_value){
  if (e.checked) {
      value_span.textContent = selected_value;
    }
    else{
      value_span.textContent = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Order Id</th>
    <th>Order Proposal Id</th>
    <th>Order Proposal Date</th>
    <th>Store Id</th>
    <th>Store Id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1001</td>
    <td>2016-10-21</td>
    <td>1709</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' onChange="printSelectedValue(this,'1001')"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>82715421</td>
    <td>2017-05-22</td>
    <td>525</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' onChange="printSelectedValue(this,'82715421')"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>82715422</td>
    <td>2016-12-31</td>
    <td>525</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' onChange="printSelectedValue(this,'82715422')"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <strong>Selected Value: <span id='selected_value'></span></strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#userTable input[type=checkbox]"));

function generateText() {
  return inputs.reduce(function(builtList, input) {
    if (input.checked) {
      return builtList.concat(input.value);
    }
    return builtList;
  }, []).join();
}

var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    textarea.value = generateText();
  });
});
```

Preferably, you'd use a better way (such as `document.getElementById()`) to select the text area, but you didn't include it in your code so I don't know its ID